# is there performance difference between system shared lib and your own lib on android?

Tags: android, webkit

i'm working on a browser app, and i compiled a webkit lib using android 2.3 source code, when i use
this so on my java framework, it's slower than the system browser.

i wonder if it's slower when using own shared lib file than system lib file, is that true?

need help.

Answer (score 0):

I think they spend a lot of time to improve their own implementations.